# sharing a folder between linux and windows over the internet

Tags: linux, windows

Currently my job is to make websites with Django. I use many things like virtualenv, PIL, etc.

The problem is, I can't stand Linux on my desktop. I like it on servers, It's greate to use it over the SSH. But for desktop? No way.

But for the development Linux is quite essential. Of course almost everything is ported to Windows, but it's not as simple to use as in Linux. For example, Windows shell is awful in comparison with Linux.

So I've tried Cygwin, but it's too damn slow. Every time django dev server reloads, it tooks almost 20-30 seconds. In comparison, then using "native" python on Windows or Linux, it reloads instantly. Even worse, Cygwin makes all my system very slow.

I've been thinking about it and have thought up a way to go. I can share a folder with my application with some Linux box. The devserver and everything will run on that box, while I'll be happy editing files and running the browser on my Windows 7. SSH shell is much quickier and handy than Cygwin.

Currently there are no Linux boxes in my home network (except for my android phone :) but I have several VDS boxes with Debian.

So, how do I share a Windows folder with VDS box?
I can't rely on my desktop IP but I can rely on the VDS's one.
I need sharing to be as quick as possible (well, 2-3 seconds ping is OK) and "native" for both systems, so I could use a folder like a normal folder in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: why do you think that the cygwin shell makes your machine slow? running the python servers through the cygwin layer, yes. but just having a shell open? (i ve done 5+ years of development in a mixed cygwin environment)

Comment: maybe just having the shell open not slows my machine down, but it's essential for me to run the server all the time

Comment: but I'm pretty sure what Cygwin itself is slow. for example, it opens for a pretty long time (dozen of seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use Dropbox to synchronize. There is a process for having a [completely terminal based setup](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall) for Dropbox and for Windows you could just use the regular client for that.

Comment: wow, great! gonna try it!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off [going the other way](http://www.expandrive.com/windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Larry, since you're on the same network, BTsync is pretty nifty.

Btsync - http://www.bittorrent.com/sync